# Put screen into power save mode instead of screen blanking

Tags: screen-saver

All normal PCs' default option for screensaver nowadays is to simply turn off the hdmi screen after some inactivity. But for the Pixel gui in Raspbian the default seems to be to turn all pixels black after inactivity (which still keeps the screen on and therefore consumes a lot of power).

How do I change the option to really turn off the screen after inactivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `hdmi_blanking=1` in config.txt.